# Laravel call to undefined method Config::get()

Tags: php, laravel-4, fatal-error

I installed an **Oauth library for social media login** in my demo project and it worked smoothly. After that i moved same code to my main project and got this **error**:

```
Call to undefined method Config::get()
```

at this line in **routes.php**

```
$config = \Config::get('socialogin::config');
```

I have already run **composer update** and published configurations of the installed library/package.

Please help me. Above code worked in demo project but not working in my main project. Both projects have same version i.e. **4.2.16**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line did the trick

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
```

I added above line at top of **routes.php** and it worked just fine.